# PayPal error code

Tags: php, paypal

I've tried looking at documentation for the API and on the web, but have not come up with much. I'm implementing PayPal with a create recurring billing profile. I keep getting the following error: Profile%20description%20is%20invalid. This error code is 11581. Does anyone know what the error could be. I set DESC=$description in the call back, where description is just a variable a define to be anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, `According to the PP docs, it indicates there is a mismatch between the original description used to setup this PayPal Express Checkout transaction, and the subsequent API call which is represented by the log entry you posted here.` (from http://www.s2member.com/forums/topic/error-generic-processor-error-11581/)

Comment: @andrewsi I didn't set in the initial creation and ran it blank for the createrecurring call and get the error though.

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622957/digital-goods-express-checkout-with-recurring-subscriptions

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks, but no, unfortunately.